# how to validate the video file with FFmpeg.wasm

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, webassembly

I want to validate the files that the user uploaded. so I can know if it is a valid mp4 or any audio type in general or not.
I'm trying to do something like that.

> `ffmpeg -v error -i file.mp4 -f null - > error.log`

when I'm running

```js
await ffmpeg.run(`-v error -sseof -60  -i ${file.name} -f null - > result.text`);
```

It shows error
`[fferr] Unrecognized option 'v error -sseof -60  -i vidoe.mp4 -f null - > result.txt'.`

what is the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution for that.

when initializing `createFFmpeg`, there is a property `logger` that requires a callback function to get log messages.

- Create an Event target to get logs

```js
const logger = new EventTarget();
```

- Init `createFFmpeg`

```js
const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({
    log: true,
    logger: (l) => {
        logger.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("log", { detail: l }));
    },
});
```

- load ffmpeg

```js
await ffmpeg.load();
```

- listen for logs

```js
let logs = [];
let log_func = (e)=>{
    logs.push({ type: e.detail.type, msg: e.detail.message });
};
logger.addEventListener("log", log_func);
```

- run ffmpeg

```js
ffmpeg.FS("writeFile", file.name, await fetchFile(file));
await ffmpeg.run("-v","error","-sseof","-60","-i",file.name,"-f","null","-");
```

- logs

```
console.log(logs);
```

- removeEventListener

```js
logger.removeEventListener("log", log_func);
```

all logs store in `logs` array